# How to get access to SPServiceContext in powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, user-profile-service

I'm having trouble getting `Get-SPServiceContext` to return a SiteSubscriptionId that is not a bunch of zeros. I'm using an account 'SP_Sync' and set permissions to

- Farm Administrators group
- User Profile Service App /w Full control
- SPShellAdmin

Is there any other permissions I need?

UPDATE:

I'm trying to access the user profile manager in powershell. All the examples I've seen are loading the context of the site in the userpfilemanager object. I can't seem to find the permissions I need to access this object.

I thought it was related to the SPServiceContext, but I can't actually run the command

```
New-Object  Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager
```

I'm receiving the error:

> New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "0" argument(s): "Value
>   cannot be null. Parameter name: serviceContext" At line:1 char:19
>   + $profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileMan ...
>   +                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Answer (score 1):

If their is no site subscription then you will get bunch of zero.

```
SiteSubscriptionId
------------------
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

But you need the following permissions(few you already have)

- farm admin group
- SPShellAdmin
- DBO rights on the Content Databases

I would run the command under the farm admin account( the account which run the SharePoint Timer services or central admin app pool).

Comment: It just has public rights on the server. Does it need the same as the sp_farm account?

Comment: in opnion yes, because these commands want to grab the information form Database....for get i think read will be fine

Comment: Is there a way to run a query on the DB for this id? I'm trying to gain access to some of the profile manager information that spuser doesn't have

Comment: what you mean run query to db server? for what?